# `git difftool -d` get 'file does not exist' error on mac

Tags: macos, git, filemerge

I am trying to use command `git difftool -d` for a folder diff.

The command get diff list successfully (show in FileMerge.app). But when I try to open each diff file. I get `file does not exist` error.

Output log:

```
$ git difftool -d 
merge tool candidates: opendiff kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff meld kompare gvimdiff diffuse ecmerge p4merge araxis bc3 codecompare emerge vimdiff
```

Image:

[image: ng image]

I am using git version 1.8.1.1 on mac OS X 10.9. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the opendiff command returns which causes difftool to delete the temp directory and all the files you are comparing.  After a ton of searching I found this, basically you have to keep that opendiff running until FileMerge exits.
change your git config to:

```
[diff]
    tool = opendiff
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "opendiff"]
    cmd = /usr/bin/opendiff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" -merge \"$MERGED\" | cat
```

found the answer here:
https://gist.github.com/bkeating/329690

Comment: The proposed configuration does not solve the problem in my environment (as *opendiff* still returns almost immediately). I opened [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33955712/1027706) where I tried to detail the steps taken and the results.

Answer (score 1):

Prevent opendiff from exiting by outputting to less or using sleep

E.g put following line to .gitconfig

```
[difftool "opendiff"]
        cmd = /usr/bin/opendiff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" -merge \"$MERGED\" | less
```