# Using OS X FileMerge/opendiff to view git differences, loading all files at once in the directory view

Tags: git, macos, filemerge, opendiff, git-difftool

We are version controlling our project using git. Developing under OS X, we'd like to use the *FileMerge* application distributed with the development tools to display git generated differences:
If we understood correctly, it is possible to configure its invocation through `git difftool`.

---

Following advices from different sources, we added this in our global git configuration file:

```
[diff]
    tool = opendiff
```

It works well for "file by file" diffs. But we prefer to have a directory difference loaded at once in the tool, for which the command is [`git difftool --dir-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool).

When invoking the directory diff command, the list of different files in correctly generated, but if we actually try to open one file, both sides show the error **files does not exist**. Apparently, this is because *opendiff* is terminating almost immediately, thus having git remove the temporary folders on which the comparison occurred.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29221361/1027706), we added those lines to our global git configuration file:

```
[difftool "opendiff"]
    cmd = /usr/bin/opendiff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" -merge \"$MERGED\" | cat
```

But it does not solve the **file does not exist** problem (and *opendiff* still returns almost immediately).

What would be the correct configuration for this use case ?

Comment: Have you considered using Xcode to view the differences instead?

Comment: @trojanfoe Thank you for the suggestion: could you please provide the appropriate configuration so we can quickly see if it fits in our workflow ?
(Also, out of curiosity/pride, we would really like to crack this opendiff nut open...)

Comment: WRT to configuration, it's just a case of exploring the repo within Xcode; but to be frank I don't do that myself.  I stick with SourceTree :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Filemerge is filtering out the `.git` directory, which is where git is storing the directory used in the output of `--dir-diff`.

In Filemerge, go to Preferences > Filters and remove `.git` from `Files to ignore` and it should work.